# Is Warrioress a real word?

Tags: grammatical-gender

According to dictionary.com the definition of [warrior](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/warrior) is:

1. a person engaged or experienced in warfare; soldier.
2. a person who shows or has shown great vigor, courage, or aggressiveness, as in politics or athletics.

I see that the noun, person, is used, rather than a particular gender; it is neutral case. But then I see a movie entitled "[Warrioress](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1723129/)." Obviously it is about a female displaying martial prowess.

Regarding the movie title specifically, is *warrioress* (changing a neutral case word into a feminine case word) a real word?

Comment: ***Warrioress*** : a female warrior. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Warrioress

Comment: The   term has probably been made more popular by movies and epic stories in recent decades : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=warrioress&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwarrioress%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It appears to be so.

Comment: The (previously, at least) more common term would be "Amazon".

Comment: Of course, in recent years, the use of feminine suffixes -ess, -ette, -trix, etc is denigrated as sexist, but so long as the fiction is set in "archaic" times, it makes sense. These days, don't try calling your restaurant "server" a waitress, though.

Comment: _XENA: Warrior Princess_ sidestepped this issue nicely; she's both a gender-neutral warrior, and a gender-specific princess. And Merida, a Disney heroine (oops, gender-specific) was both a princess and a Brave.

Comment: The question "is X a real world" is ... an incorrect or at least imprecise  question. There simply **is no** final arbiter of word or spelling popularity.

Comment: That is how a lot of language works. You have a gender neutral and a female specific variant.

Comment: You have a male and a female variant and default to male form, as allegedly evidenced by the Parliament Interpretation Act of 1850 (showing entrenchment in law), default to male form. This is likely since historical gender roles made it more likely for men to encounter other men during the course of their careers, especially in battle. Webster's 1828 & 1913 dictionaries both list [warrior](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=warrior&resource=Webster%27s) specifically as a man and [warrioress](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=warrioress&resource=Webster's) as a woman.

Comment: @JoeBlow I voted to close due to lack of clarity.

Comment: Use it and you'll get your head chopped off.

Comment: Are you going to tell her it isn't a real word?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in the OED, it has citations back to the 16th century:

> 1594   R. Carew tr. Tasso *Godfrey of Bulloigne* iii. 110   Now to the combat had this warriouresse Plighted her selfe.
>
> 1596   Spenser *Second Pt. Faerie Queene* v. vii. sig. S2,   Eftsoones that warriouresse with haughty crest Did forth issue, all ready for the fight.

It has also been used (rarely) for the last two centuries, so it's not obsolete. I think it counts as a word.

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, it doesn't seem to be widely recognised as a word. However, Merriam-Webster acknowledges it:

> **[warrioress](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warrioress)**
>
> a female warrior

(It may be worth pointing out that Internet Explorer's spellchecker underlined "warrioress" as incorrect, suggesting the much more common "warrior".)

Comment: please, don't use Internet Explorer for truth in any regard!

Comment: @zonabi I agree, IE 6 to IE 8 were bad, but IE 9 and above are actually decent browsers! The problem is people won't give IE a second chance. (And before you turn this into a war, I also use Chrome, Edge and Firefox.)